# Meteor controlling copying and pasting in a text field

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to prevent copying and pasting white spaces in the username field inside my Meteor app template but I am always getting an error as shown below, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong / missing and is there any other way to control content pasted in a text field in Meteor template? Thanks

```
        Template.UserRegisteration.events({
            'input #username':function(e,t){     
                 this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g,'');
            }   
        });
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Akshat mentioned to get field DOM element use e.currentTarget instead of this, back to your question code sample please try the following

```
    Template.UserRegisteration.events({
        'input #username':function(e,t){     
             var text = e.currentTarget.value;
             e.currentTarget.value = text.replace(/\s/g,'');
        }   
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is the context is the data context where the `input id="username` field is.

To get the field's DOM element use `e.currentTarget` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

The following example sets out how to extract and set the value of a DOM element within a Meteor event:

https://www.meteor.com/try/4

```
Template.body.events({
  "submit .new-task": function (event) {
    // This function is called when the new task form is submitted

    var text = event.target.text.value;

    Tasks.insert({
      text: text,
      createdAt: new Date() // current time
    });

    // Clear form
    event.target.text.value = "";

    // Prevent default form submit
    return false;
  }
});
```

Within a Meteor events block, "this" is not the DOM element so you cannot call a value on it.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code in the answer itself. If the link dies, your answer will be plain useless.

Comment: I am trying to track the on input event as shown in my question, unfortunately using event.target.text.value returns error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined